# Uniqueness of the solutions on Riemann-Hilbert problem

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I've read a review paper on Seiberg-Witten theory, [Introduction to Seiberg-Witten theory and its stringy origin](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9611190) and found a statement about [Riemann-Hilbert problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Hilbert_problem). The author said in the first paragraph of section 2.4

> The physics problem has now become a mathematical one, namely simply to ﬁnd multi-valued functions $a(u)$, $a_D(u)$ that display the required monodromies $M_{±Λ^2,\infty}$ around the singularities (and that in addition lead to a coupling $\tau\equiv\partial_a a_D$ with $\mathrm{Im}\,\tau>0$). This is a classical mathematical problem, the “Riemann-Hilbert” problem, which is known to have a unique$^6$ solution.

with footnote 6

> Unique up to multiplication of $(a_D(u),a(u))$ by an entire function; this can however be ﬁxed by imposing the correct, semi-classical asymptotic behavior.

My question is how can I confirm the statement "The solution ($(a_D,a)$ for this specific case) of Riemann-Hilbert problem is **unique up to multiplication by an entire function**"? Is it very well-known fact in mathematics?

Comment: If $f(a+e^{z+2i\pi}) =h_a(z) f(a+e^{z})$ and $f_2(z) = f(z) g(z)$ for some analytic function $g$ then $f_2(a+e^{z+2i\pi}) =h_a(z) f_2(a+e^{z})$. $f$ is analytic at $a$ iff $h_a \equiv 1$.

Comment: @reuns Thanks. I made a little change in the question. I'm asking about the uniqueness of the solution on Riemann-Hilbert problem. Whether it is determined up to entire function or not.

Comment: I think the footnote just says that multiplication by an entire function doesn't change the monodromy group, and quotient of two such "solutions" is meromorphic

Comment: @reuns I agree with you. But are the entire functions only possibility to retain monodromy group?